How to always start Kodi on boot up?
What is the best or most recommended way to configure Ubuntu 24.04 such that Kodi will always be automatically run upon boot-up, and such that no password will be required on boot to boot Ubuntu?
I know all about LibreELEC. Due to a certain quite troublesome bug (i.e. constantly losing the WiFi password on each reboot) in LibreELEC, that (LibreELEC) is not an option for me. There are other reasons why I prefer to use full Linux also, specifically built-in kernel NFS support.

I'd work out what you're actually running (there is no Ubuntu 24.x) where by you can tell the system the autostart what you want. If you installed a desktop; you could have your DM autostart a kodi session (what I've done in the past); but you didn't mention if your install is Server, Desktop giving only an invalid release... so first step is working out what you're using as

Does 24.x mean Ubuntu 24.04 or does it mean 24.10?

Sorry.  To clarify I was only asking about Ubuntu 24.04 desktop edition.

One way (assuming you are running Ubuntu dekstop):
Enable Automatic Logon by going to Settings -> System -> Users which will start Ubuntu without needing a password. Although it won't unlock the password keyring so if you do something later that requires the keyring it will prompt for the user password.
Run the default Startup Applications app and add an entry which runs kodi or whatever the name of the command line is.
